# Can 1-wire (One-wire) sensors be used over power lines?

Tags: sensor, power-line-communication

I'd like to sprinkle my house with 1-wire sensors ([temperature](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004G53D54) - everywhere, humidity and flooding - in the basement), but the only wire in most locations is the power-socket (110V)...

Can a 1-wire microlan simply coexist with the AC power without short-circuiting and without the readings getting lost? If not, perhaps, [HomePlug AV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug_AV) devices can be used?

Answer (score 1):

The device you inquired about, the [DS18B20](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf), can not be directly connected to AC power circuits.  It requires a DC supply of 3.0 to 5.5V.  Some sort of power-line modem or interface circuit, at a minimum, would be necessary to connect a raw sensor IC such as this to an AC power line circuit.  Anything that involves communications over 110V AC power mains should not be considered a "do it yourself" kind of projet.  I would suggest sticking to the Home Plug AV devices you mentioned, or similar commercial power line communications devices.

Comment: Any idea, if HomePlug AV devices can be used to simply pass a signal (simulating 4 twisted pairs found in an Ethernet cable), or must I use actual Ethernet protocol to get data through the AC-power wiring? Thanks!